# Saving in memory file object with pillow

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

In my django project I have a inmemoryuploadedfile, I then open this with Pillow, rotate it, and save it back to itself. The last step doesn't actually work however. When I save it to a file the correct(rotated) image is saved. How can I save back to the file object instead of an actual file?

```
    image = request.FILES['file']
    img = Image.open(image)
    img = img.rotate(90)
    img.save("sample.jpeg", "jpeg") #this is correct
    img.save(image, "jpeg") #this does not change the actual in memory image
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to reset the the stream position of the underlying StreamIO-object that holds your uploaded file. Otherwise `Image.save()` will only append to the end of the stream.

You might also need to reset stream position before trying to read the file from memory again.

```
image = request.FILES['file']
img = Image.open(image)
img = img.rotate(90)
image.seek(0)
img.save(image, "jpeg")
image.seek(0)
image.read()
```

Note that `UploadedFile` (base class of `InMemoryUploadedFile`) keeps track of the file size, and if you are changing the underlying file object, code depending on the `InMemoryUploadedFile.size` may get confused.

Comment: Can I somehow reset the length? All i'm doing is rotating the image but pillow does strip exif data so the file must be getting somewhat smaller.

Comment: You should be able to update the file size by just setting image.size to the new value. You can even try to use the _get_size_from_underlying_file() method found here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/base.py#L39. Like image.size = image._get_size_from_underlying_file()